# Why isn't this BASH array building?

Tags: bash

Why isn't this bash array populating? I believe I've done them like this in the past. Echoing `${#XECOMMAND[@]}` shows no data..

```
DIR=$1
TEMPFILE=/tmp/dir.tmp

ls -l $DIR | tail -n +2 |  sed 's/\s\+/ /g' | cut -d" " -f5,9 > $TEMPFILE


i=0
cat $TEMPFILE | while read line ;do

    if [[ $(echo $line | cut -d" " -f1) == 0 ]]; then

        XECOMMAND[$i]="$(echo "$line" | cut -d" " -f2)"
        (( i++ ))   
    fi

done
```

Comment: It's probably the subshell caused by the pipe. Try like this: `while ...... done < "$TEMPFILE"`

Comment: That did it user000001, thank you.

Comment: I'm curious why this method didn't work though? Can you post your answer below also? I'd love to give you credit

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if it is clear enough

Comment: Using `ls` in scripts like this is a very bad idea; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for a discussion of why. What are you _actually_ trying to accomplish, so we can provide a better, more robust approach?

Comment: I'm running through a directory, creating an array of the 0 length files (empty text files), passing the array to another script that populates them, and then dumping the populated text files in their directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the while loop like

```
somecommand | while read ...
```

then the while loop is executed in sub-shell, i.e. a different process than the main script. Thus, all variable assignments that happen in the loop, will not be reflected in the main process. The workaround is to use input redirection and/or command substitution, so that the loop executes in the current process. For example if you want to read from a file you do

```
while read ....
do
    # do stuff
done < "$filename"
```

or if you wan't the output of a process you can do

```
while read ....
do
    # do stuff
done < <(some command)
```

Finally, in bash 4.2 and above, you can set `shopt -s lastpipe`, which causes the last command in the pipeline to be executed in the current process.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to construct an array consisting of the names of all zero-length files and directories in `$DIR`. If so, you can do it like this:

```
mapfile -t ZERO_LENGTH < <(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -size 0)
```

(Add `-type f` to the find command if you're only interested in regular files.)

This sort of solution is almost always better than trying to parse `ls` output.

The use of process substitution (`< <(...)`) rather than piping (`... |`) is important, because it means that the shell variable will be set in the current shell, not in an ephimeral subshell.